# Ошибка при попытке прописать одно значение для строк в столбце в pandas (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Имеется excel таблица, в которой часть данных я беру из другой таблицы, а часть прописываю по умолчанию.
Выглядит это примерно так:

```
    res_file = pd.read_excel('name.xlsx', header=0)
    data = pd.read_excel(path)
```

```
    res_file['Код'] = range(1, 1 + len(data['Вопрос']) )
    res_file['Заголовок вопроса'] = data['Вопрос']
    res_file['Тип вопроса'] = ['multiple_choice' for i in templ['Тип вопроса']]
    res_file['Текст вопроса'] = data['Вопрос']
```

При попытке прописать значения циклом, как в "Тип вопроса" - вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\io\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Тип вопроса'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/io/github/itables/tables.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/io/github/itables/tables.py", line 108, in main
    merge(s_path, file_name)
  File "C:/Users/io/github/itables/tables.py", line 87, in merge
    templ['Тип вопроса'] = ['multiple_choice' for i in templ['Тип вопроса']]
  File "C:\Users\io\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\io\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Тип вопроса'
```

Не могу понять в чем причина, ранее подобные циклы работали исправно

Comment: Ну видимо в `templ` нет колонки 'Тип вопроса'

Comment: Это я проверил в первую очередь, нет, проблема именно в цикле.
Для всех столбцов, где задействован цикл - такая же ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первым решением оказалось не использовать данные циклы, то есть записать в данном виде:

```
    templ['Код'] = range(1, 1 + len(data['Вопрос']) )
    templ['Заголовок вопроса'] = data['Вопрос']
    templ['Тип вопроса'] = 'multiple_choice'
    templ['Текст вопроса'] = data['Вопрос']
```

Почему-то этот очевидный вариант работает не всегда, иногда приходится делать вышеупомянутый цикл. Вероятно, связано с внутренним отличием стандартного dataframe от excel dataframe формата